# invalid operands to binary expression ('char ()' and 'int')

Tags: c, integer, initialization, declaration, scalar

`I've been trying this code to show if a number that I type is even or odd, but it gets an error when I run it:

ERROR:`

```
 make -s
./main.c:8:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char ()' and 'int')
  if(numero % 2 == 0){
     ~~~~~~ ^ ~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:10: main] Error 1
exit status 2
```

`CODE:`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char number();
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &number);

   if (number % 2 == 0) {
     printf("%d is even", number);
   } else {
     printf("%d is odd", number);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

`I tried searching the same error here, but it doesn't fix my error`

Comment: You can't just type some random code in a source editor... `char number();` is nonsense and that's about it. Swap it to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`char number();` declares a function prototype because of the round brackets at the end. The compiler thinks `number` is a function returning a `char`. Therefore in

```
if (number % 2 == 0)
```

`number` is a function pointer and it makes no sense to divide it by 2.

`number` should be declared as an `int` if you are using `%d` i.e.

```
int number;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C initializers are supplied after the sign `=` in declarations

```
declarator = initializer
```

and (the C Standard, 6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces.** The initial value of the object is
> that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints
> and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the
> scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

In this declaration in your program

```
char number();
```

there is absent the sign `=`. This line declares a function that has the return type `char`  and unknown number and types of parameters.

If you want to declare an object of the type `int` according to these statements

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

then declare it like

```
int number;
```

or you could initialize it with zero like

```
int number = 0;
```

or

```
int number = { 0 };
```

If your compiler supports C23 Standard then you can also write

```
int number = {};
```

It is desirable to check whether the input was successful. So you can write for example

```
if ( scanf("%d", &number) == 1 )
{
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        printf("%d is even\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("%d is odd\n", number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable you use is of type char, in your case you need an integer

```
   #include <stdio.h>
`  int main(void) {
   int number;
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &number);

   if ( number % 2 == 0) {
     printf("%d is even", number);
   } else {
     printf("%d is odd", number);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `char` would have been fine (encoding/wide characters aside), it was the fact it was declared as `char number();` (a function prototype).

Comment: @Rogue A `char` may not have been fine depending on the implementation. `%d` means the C library expects the pointer to point to something big enough to hold an `int`.